# Condensing write.target lines into one?

Tags: python

I'm learning python with "learning python the hard way", and I'm having trouble with [exercise 16:](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex16.html) with the study drill. How do I convert the following six lines of code into one? :

```
target.write(line1)
target.write("\n")
target.write(line2)
target.write("\n")
target.write(line3)
target.write("\n")
```

I went on to try this:

```
lines = line1,"\n",line2,"\n",line3,"\n"
target.write(lines)
```

But that didn't seem to work either, in terminal it said: 
expected a character buffer object

After referring to exercise 6 I then tried:

```
lines = "%s\n%s\n%s\n" % line1,line2,line3
target.write(lines)
```

and it then says in the terminal "TypeError: not enough arguments for format string"

Also tried:

```
target.write("%s,\n,%s,\n,%s,\n" % line1,line2,line3)
```

And got the same problem

Comment: Wrap `line1,line2,line3` in `()`.

Comment: Not quite - you only want to wrap with `()` for the format string, like this: `lines = "%s\n%s\n%s\n" % (line1,line2,line3)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
target.write('\n'.join(lines)) #assuming all the line #s are put in a list called "lines"
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Exercise 6](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex6.html), and then take a look at the information you're writing - it kind of looks like this, doesn't it?

`'<line>\n<line>\n<line>\n'`

Exercise 6 should get you up to speed enough to solve this.

Comment: I have tried something along the lines (excuse the pun) of this:

lines = line1,"\n",line2,"\n",line3,"\n"
target.write(lines)

But that didn't work

Comment: Take a look at the line `print "I also said: '%s'." % y` in Exercise 6 - that's what you need.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me using python 2.7

```
Lines = "%s\n%s\n%s" % (Line1, Line2, Line3)

target.write(Lines)
```

or

```
target.write("%s\n%s\n%s" % (Line1, Line2, Line3))
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading the Answer about exercise 6 (I would comment my post but I can't :o ) I wrote this code:

```
line1 = raw_input("line 1: ")
line2 = raw_input("line 2: ")
line3 = raw_input("line 3: ")
newline = "\n"

print "Now I 'm going to write these to the file."

target.write(line1 + newline + line2 + newline + line3 + newline)
```

And it worked like a charm!